# Need help splitting this string of names (first name and last name pairs delimited by commas and "and")

Tags: regex, perl

I'm using perl and need to split strings of author names delimited by commas as well as a last "and". The names are formed as first name and last name, looking like this:

```
$string1 = "Joe Smith, Jason Jones, Jane Doe and Jack Jones";
$string2 = "Joe Smith, Jason Jones, Jane Doe, and Jack Jones";
$string3 = "Jane Doe and Joe Smith";
# Next line doesn't work because there is no comma between last two names
@data = split(/,/, $string1);
```

I would just like to split the full names into elements of an array, like what split() would do, so that the @data array would contain, for example:

```
@data[0]: "Joe Smith"
@data[1]: "Jason Jones"
@data[2]: "Jane Doe"
@data[3]: "Jack Jones"
```

However, the problem is that there is no comma between the last two names in the lists. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What will you do with "names" like "Joe Smith, MD and Mary and Joe Smith"?

Comment: note, you don't use `@data[1]` but rather `$data[1]`. Since you are only using one element, it is a scalar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a simple alternation in your regular expression for split:

```
my @parts = split(/\s*,\s*|\s+and\s+/, $string1);
```

For example:

```
$ perl -we 'my $string1 = "Joe Smith, Jason Jones, Jane Doe and Jack Jones";print join("\n",split(/\s*,\s*|\s+and\s+/, $string1)),"\n"'
Joe Smith
Jason Jones
Jane Doe
Jack Jones

$ perl -we 'my $string2 = "Jane Doe and Joe Smith";print join("\n",split(/\s*,\s*|\s+and\s+/, $string2)),"\n"'
Jane Doe
Joe Smith
```

If you also have to deal with the Oxford Comma (i.e. "this, that, and the other thing"), then you could use

```
my @parts = split(/\s*,\s*and\s+|\s*,\s*|\s+and\s+/, $string1);
```

For example:

```
$ perl -we 'my $s = "Joe Smith, Jason Jones, Jane Doe, and Jack Jones";print join("\n",split(/\s*,\s*and\s+|\s*,\s*|\s+and\s+/, $s)),"\n"'
Joe Smith
Jason Jones
Jane Doe
Jack Jones

$ perl -we 'my $s = "Joe Smith, Jason Jones, Jane Doe and Jack Jones";print join("\n",split(/\s*,\s*and\s+|\s*,\s*|\s+and\s+/, $s)),"\n"'
Joe Smith
Jason Jones
Jane Doe
Jack Jones

$ perl -we 'my $s = "Joe Smith and Jack Jones";print join("\n",split(/\s*,\s*and\s+|\s*,\s*|\s+and\s+/, $s)),"\n"'
Joe Smith
Jack Jones
```

Thanks to [stackoverflowuser2010](https://stackoverflow.com/users/307099/stackoverflowuser2010) for noting this case.

You'll want the `\s*,\s*and\s+` at the beginning to keep the other branches of the alternation from splitting on the comma or "and" first, [this order appears to be guaranteed as well](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Version-8-Regular-Expressions):

> Alternatives are tried from left to right, so the first alternative found for which the entire expression matches, is the one that is chosen.

Comment: @ysth: You may guess that I started with `\s*(...)\s*` and refined it to remove the badness.

Comment: What is the benefit of the group in this solution rather than just the | as @yslth suggested?

Comment: @cftarnas: The benefit is the ysth gets to point out my oversight :)

Comment: Interestingly, this code doesn't work if the input has a comma in front of the 'and'. For example: "Joe Smith, Jason Jones, Jane Doe, and Jack Jones".

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010: I've updated to account for the Oxford Comma, thanks for point that out.

Comment: Thanks. I also didn't know there was a name for that comma: the Oxford Comma. Learning something new each day.

Comment: It’s not just Oxford that recommends the comma; many sources do, including Strunk&White and the Chicago Manual of Style. And all technical publications I’ve ever read require it. Frankly, I hate reading stuff without it. “I wish to thank my parents, Mother Theresa and Jesus.” There should be no special cases.

Comment: @tchrist: No special cases in English? Ha ha ha ha ha. I use it for the obvious reasons and it irritates me when it isn't present (almost as much as misspelling "their"). And Mother Theresa isn't one of your parents.

Answer (score 4):

Before `split`, replace `and` with a `,`:

```
$string1 =~ s{\s+and\s+}{,}g;
```